# Sqlite - change date format

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, sql-update

is there any way to change this format in Sqlite to work with select

[image]

to normal date format, for example(yyyy-mm-dd) ??

Comment: Is it the full month or the 3 letter month abbreviation? E.g. is it  2021JAN10 or 2021JANUARY10?

Comment: 3 letter month abbreviation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doe not support any function that can transform a month's name or abbreviation to a number.
This can be done with a CTE that does the mapping and then a join to the table:

```
WITH cte(month, month_name) AS (VALUES
  ('01', 'JAN'), ('02', 'FEB'), ('03', 'MAR'), ('04', 'APR'), ('05', 'MAY'), ('06', 'JUN'), 
  ('07', 'JUL'), ('08', 'AUG'), ('09', 'SEP'), ('10', 'OCT'), ('11', 'NOV'), ('12', 'DEC') 
)
SELECT SUBSTR(t.col, 1, 4) || '-' || c.month || '-' || printf('%02d', SUBSTR(t.col, 8)) date
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
ON t.col LIKE '%' || c.month_name || '%'
ORDER BY date;
```

If you want to update the table:

```
WITH cte(month, month_name) AS (VALUES
  ('01', 'JAN'), ('02', 'FEB'), ('03', 'MAR'), ('04', 'APR'), ('05', 'MAY'), ('06', 'JUN'), 
  ('07', 'JUL'), ('08', 'AUG'), ('09', 'SEP'), ('10', 'OCT'), ('11', 'NOV'), ('12', 'DEC') 
)
UPDATE tablename AS t
SET col = SUBSTR(t.col, 1, 4) || '-' || 
          (SELECT c.month FROM cte c WHERE t.col LIKE '%' || c.month_name || '%') || '-' || 
          printf('%02d', SUBSTR(t.col, 8))
```

Replace `col` with the name of the column.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e0d35850b5d872c7ade5513ffa88de3a).